# Websharper : Using LI tags

Tags: f#, websharper

I want to create something like that :

```
<ul>
    <li>menu1
         <ul>
             <li>sub-menu1</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>menu2</li>
</ul>
```

So i write the following code using WebSharper :

```
let el =
        UL [
            LI [
                Text "menu1"
                UL [
                    LI [Text "sub-menu1"]
                ]
            ]
            LI [Text "menu2"]
        ]
```

But it says that

```
UL [
    LI [Text "sub-menu1"]
]
```

should have the type `IPagelet` but currently have the type `Element`.

Does anyone have an idea on how to put a text + something else under an li element using WebSharper ?

Edit: Just to say that I have a bug on stakc, I can't comment or accepted the answer of @Tarmil...

Comment: If you need text and another element (say `Strong`), I ended up using Span to wrap the text: `[ LI [ Span [ Text "sub-menu1 "]; [ Strong [Text "is awesome" ] ] ] ]`

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson Tanks for the tips. It's was actually to build a menu using JQueryUI.

Comment: No prob: I'm still learning WebSharper too. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that two elements in the same list, `Text "menu1"` and `UL [...]`, have types `IPagelet` and `Element` respectively. `Element` is a subtype of `IPagelet`, so this should work, but unfortunately the F# type inference has some difficulties with this situation. So you need to help it by casting `UL [...]` to `IPagelet`:

```
let el =
    UL [
        LI [
            Text "menu1"
            UL [
                LI [Text "sub-menu1"]
            ] :> IPagelet
        ]
        LI [Text "menu2"]
    ]
```

In fact, this problem would be eliminated if the combinators had type `seq<IPagelet> -> Element` instead of `seq<#IPagelet> -> Element`. We will probably change them to that in the future, but since it would be a breaking change, we're keeping it for the next major version.

Comment: yeah this is a pain - but `-<` will help a lot if you just split things like `Attr.Class` and the contents (indeed it even makes the code more readable) - here you can try `LI [Text "menu"] -< [ UL [ ... ] ]`